# Four subspaces associated with the matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Describe the $4$ subspaces associated with the following matrix:

$A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0\\0 & 0 & 1\\0&  0& 0 \end{bmatrix}$

Prof. Strang writes that the nullspace contains only zero vector but it contains also $\begin{bmatrix}1 &0 &0\end{bmatrix}$ which is easily found bu setting $x_1 = 0$. Am I missing something?

Comment: Which 4 subspaces anyway? Null space, column space, row space and eigenspace?

Comment: Do you mean $x_1=1$? Then $[1 \ 0 \ 0] $ is an element of the null space of the given matrix.

Comment: Nullspace, column space, row space and left nullspace. Yes, [1 0 0] should by in the nullspace. However, Strang writes that nullspace contains only zero vector. I don't understand why this should be case

Comment: The last row is zero. Where's your doubt?

Comment: Does nullspace really contain only zero vector? This is my question

Comment: In this case it contains more than the zero vector. Try doing the multiplication. This is also clear since the matrix has rank $2 <3$.

Comment: Yes, I also know this, there are n-r=1 free variable so nullspace contains vector other than zero vector. However, Strang claims that there is only zero vector in the nullspace of this matrix. That's why I was confused